# How to limit login access and create ban after 4 attempts to web application based on user's IP address?

Tags: javascript, java, security, login

i have created the js file for this purpose but i cannot find a way to limit the access after 3 failed attempts based on user's ip address. can someone please suggest me a way to do that? i do not have spring on my application, just simple java servlets and jsps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure `fail2ban` to watch your webserver logs.  Just be sure to log something when a login fails to your web app.

Note - if the person who fails is behind NAT, you'll be blocking *all* people coming from behind that address.  In theory, this lets one person's actions block an entire college, corporation, etc.